# IOS tools to discover a network

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, network-discovery

I would like to learn/discover a new topology. I usually use these commands. Do you know any other good tools for this? (the network have routers, switches, firewalls, multiple vrfs, vlans and all kind of stuff :) )

- show arp
- sho cdp (sometimes enabled)
- ping and traceroute
- sho ip route ..
- sho ip eigrp/ospf/bgp/rip ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a very very useful GUI tool from Cisco called Cisco Network Assistance can help you to discover the entire network with all details you need to know about it.where you can discover your network community by the Rang (start and end IPs)
Or by supnet defined with mask and once you start to discover it will discover all the network and will draw the topology layout and rack layout of your devices.even Cisco IP phones and access point
[image]

[image]

also it can generate health report for all devices include the CPU usage and temperature and FAN speed 
[image]

it can also be used to trubleshoot connectivity problems (cascadded devices or loops) and it can also be used for simple configurations like add vlans or configur port for access vlans or trunk . what i very like in it it also can draw stacked switched to gether in both topology layout and rack layout

[image]

Comment: This tool is free by the way

Comment: Only caveat is CNA only supports a max of 80 devices currently if the network to be scanned is small I'm in agreement that CNA is the way to go for Cisco devices. If the network is larger there are many free open source tools that can scan large networks.

Comment: I agree with you It is very helpful with cisco only may I make other post for open source tools I try it